# DLL関数の呼び出しエラーについて

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

現在、古いVisual StudioのSolutionをビルドしています。
全部で100もあったエラーが残りが10個くらいのLINKエラーだけになりました。
その残りのエラーの一つが次のエラーです。

「エラー LNK2019 未解決の外部シンボル _sprintf が関数 "void __cdecl ****で参照されました。」

「_sprintf」はランタイムライブラリであり、「__cdecl *****」は「\project\myjpeglib.lib(jerror.obj)」のものです。そしてこの「myjpeglib.lib」は、2006年にビルドされたものです。

この「_sprintf」が当時の呼び出し方から現在の呼び出し方に変わったということは考えられないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 重複候補: [「エラーLNK1104ファイル 'LIBCD.lib' を開くことができません。」への対処法について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/45155/%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bclnk1104%e3%83%95%e3%82%a1%e3%82%a4%e3%83%ab-libcd-lib-%e3%82%92%e9%96%8b%e3%81%8f%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93-%e3%81%b8%e3%81%ae%e5%af%be%e5%87%a6%e6%b3%95%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6)

Comment: `LIBCD.lib`も`sprintf`もCランタイムライブラリであり、指摘の質問が解決すれば本エラーは解消されます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。しかし、「LIBCD.lib」の解決方法とこの問題の解決方法はどうも異なるようです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: まずは「古いプロジェクトをビルドしようとするとエラーになる」で質問をまとめておき、性質が異なるエラーと分かった時点で改めて質問も分けた方がよいのではないでしょうか？

Comment: もう一つ追加情報をします。『\project\myjpeglib.lib(jerror.obj)」というところからこのエラーを出しています。

Comment: もう一つ情報を追加します。この「myjpeglib.lib」は、2006年にビルドされたもののようですので、当時のsprintfと現在のsprintfの呼び出し方法が違うのかもしれません。

Comment: コメントに追加情報を記述するのではなく、編集を行い質問文を完成させてください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

最近のVSでは　sprintf() sscanf() 等がインライン化されているので、現在のCランタイムライブラリには含まれていません。
昔ビルドされたライブラリ等は、昔のCランタイムに存在している実体をリンクしようとするので見つからないというエラーになるのだと想像できます。

色々なページで紹介されている様に、legacy_stdio_definitions.libをリンクするという方法が良いかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。早速試してみます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。お陰様で、このリンクエラーは解消されました。