# "error:LNK1104ファイル 'LIBC.lib' を開くことができません。"への対処法について

Tags: visual-c++

Visual Studio Pro 2013 update 5を使用しております。
古いプロジェクト(VC6)作成のプロジェクトを変換してコンパイルしたところ、以下のエラーが出ます。

```
error:LNK1104ファイル 'LIBC.lib' を開くことができません。
```

本サイト内を検索したところ、以下の投稿を見つけました。

[「エラーLNK1104ファイル 'LIBCD.lib' を開くことができません。」への対処法について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/45155)

しかし、そこで紹介されている解決策（リンカーオプションを/MTや/MDにする）をしても、今回のエラーは解決しませんでした。

他にはどこをチェックして、どのように修正すればよいでしょうか。
ご教示ください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: プロジェクトのプロパティやソースコードのプラグマの中にリンク時のオプションとして明示的に`LIBC`が含まれているのかもしれませんね。そうした指定や情報を探してみてください。

Comment: 既に不要かもしれませんが、この記事 [upgrading app in Visual C++ 6.0 to Visual Studio 2013](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5d0aca30-a1f3-494c-87d2-5878db61909c/) でいったんVisualStudio2008でプロジェクトを変換してからVisualStudio2013に移行すると比較的簡単に出来ると書いてあります。VisualStudio2008はサブスクリプション契約を行っていればvisualstudio.comのサブスクリプションライブラリから入手出来るでしょう。他に解決していませんがコメントが多数ついているこんな記事とか。[Best way to migrate Visual C++ 6.0 to Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34649592/9014308)

Comment: 情報をありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。コンパイルが通らないプロジェクトはもう古すぎるので、１から作り直すことも視野に入れて検討します。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージに出ている`LIBC.lib`はシングルスレッド・リリース版のCRTライブラリです。[Visual Studio 2005 の重要な変更点 - CRT](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/porting/visual-cpp-change-history-2003-2015?view=msvc-170#crt-2)には

> シングルスレッドの CRT ライブラリ libc.lib と libcd.lib は削除されました。 マルチスレッドの CRT ライブラリを使用してください。 /ML コンパイラ フラグはサポートされなくなりました。 マルチスレッドのコードとシングルスレッドのコード間のパフォーマンスの違いが重要な問題になる場合に、一部の関数のロックなしバージョンが追加されました。

と説明のある通り、Visual Studio 2005以降はシングルスレッド版のCRTライブラリは廃止されました。マルチスレッド版のCRTライブラリに移行する必要があります。

本来、`LIBC.lib`にリンクしているオブジェクトファイルを再コンパイルすべきです。

---

`LIBC.lib`にリンクしているオブジェクトファイルにソースコードが存在せず再コンパイルできない場合でも努力と根性で何とかなるかもしれません。ただし、シングルスレッドを前提にコーディングおよびコンパイルがされているため正常に動作する保証はありません。

1. [リンクオプション `/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBC`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/build/reference/nodefaultlib-ignore-libraries?view=msvc-170) を追加します
2. （リンクエラーが発生する場合）`LIBCMT.lib`を追加します
3. （Visual Studio 2015以降でリンクエラーが発生する場合）`legacy_stdio_definitions.lib`を追加します

Comment: 詳細に説明をいただき感謝いたします。古いプロジェクトをそのままコンパイルを通そうとするのをやめて、１から再作しなおす方向で考えたいと思います。